# Pure HTML 5 WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently using TinyMCE as a rich content editor for my JQuery application, but with the advent of Html 5 and its "contenteditable" attribute it seems the iframe trick that it uses is no longer needed.

Are there any cross browser Html 5 WYSIWYG Editor out there? I know Html 5 stuff isn't compatible with older browsers but that doesn't concern as I am making an experimental Html 5 everything website.

Comment: A search engine is a very powerful thing. (First hit: http://aloha-editor.org/, but there are probably many more out there.)

Comment: SO is not a recommendation engine: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 3):

You could have searched Google before! Did you see [WYSIHTML5](http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/)?

> #### WYSIHTML5 - A better approach to rich text editing
>
> Open source rich text editor based on HTML5 and the
> progressive-enhancement approach. Uses a sophisticated security
> concept and aims to generate fully valid HTML5 markup by preventing
> unmaintainable tag soups and inline styles.
>
> wysihtml5 is an open source rich text editor based on HTML5 technology
> and the progressive-enhancement approach. It uses a sophisticated
> security concept and aims to generate fully valid HTML5 markup by
> preventing unmaintainable tag soups and inline styles.

Comment: Some helpful information...WYSIHTML5 looks like a good plugin, but setup is a pain in terms of getting the editor to look like the demo page.  Styles and images for the editor buttons are not included, and you have to either set them yourself, or scrape them off of the demo site.  Many of the the other options out there are more "out-of-the-box" usable without a lot of extra work.

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE 4.0 now supports HTML 5 and inline editing feature. You can take a look at demo: http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php

Answer (score 0):

[BlueGriffon](http://bluegriffon.org/) has HTML5 and CSS3 support.