# Html -- How to add an editor for an input text field?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, editor

I know there has too many JS libraries can do this, such as: Trumbowyg, etc.

But before my rails project renders that slim, must escape javascript!

So, I must make an editor which is made up of pure Html or Ruby. But how to make?

(Note: pure Html and Ruby!)

Answer (score 1):

The most popular is TinyMCE. You can implement it easily and it is pure HTML, for your part at least.

https://www.tiny.cloud/

Answer (score 0):

Does yout need lightweight WYSIWYG editor? If yes, try to choose any **lightweight** editor [from this list](https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable/wiki/Javascript-WYSIWYG-editors)
Also I find out related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172054/pure-html-5-wysiwyg-editor).